# Debugging in source code of meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, visual-studio-code

I have an application on `meteor` but I can't run it, because runtime gives `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. I know that error was initiated in source code of `meteor`, and I can't find out why. I want to debug my app with stepping into meteor.js sources. How can I do this in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Why don't you use `console.log()` instead of debugging whatever you desire?

Comment: In order to debug the Meteor source itself, I believe that you would have to clone the meteor repo and run it as a node app with the node debugger, not really a trivial task. This is what I did to track a Meteor bug. For your purposes, I would not recommend it the default solution. Try to find the issue in your code first (e.g, exclude some files from being included to detect the file containing the issue). Also, use the stack trace to figure out what meteor complains about.

Comment: @AnkurSoni I don't know why, but I really don't think this direction) It would be great workaround for me

Comment: @MasterAM I do want to go exactly this way and already have cloned the meteor.js repo. But I don't know how to run meteor from this repo with my application project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode has meteor debugging capability for both client and server. Worth looking at using that. https://code.visualstudio.com/

Here is a recipe on setting it up with Meteor

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/meteor

> This recipe shows how to use the built-in Node Debugger and the
>   Debugger for Chrome extension with VS Code to debug meteor
>   applications.
>
> Meteor is used to write applications that runs on both on the server
>   and client with the same code, and this is a great match for VS Code,
>   as we can debug both the server and client at the same time! This
>   means that you'll need to use two debugger instances within VS Code to
>   debug both ends. This is the reason for why you'll need both the
>   built-in Node Debugger and the Debugger for Chrome.